# How to tell if Remote Desktop service is running and available?

Tags: remote-desktop, notifications

This is a problem that I have wanted to find a solution for, for quite a while.  However, it always falls off my radar.  It just reared its annoying head again and I finally decided to look for a solution.  I just cant find one.

So I was just Remote Desktopped onto a server and rebooted it.  Normally I just type `ping -t servername` in a command window to see when the server comes back up.  However, just because the server is up, does not mean the remote Desktop Services have started and are available again.  I sit there a click connect on MSTSC or RDCM over and over until it pops up.

Is there a tool out there that can notify a user that a remote machines RD services are ready?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [NMAP/Zenmap](http://nmap.org/) on your machine.  Just point it at the server like so:

> nmap -PN -sS -p 3389 ip-of-machine

Or you can use the GUI version, Zenmap and just plug all that in to the GUI.

Comment: you sir, are my hero.

Comment: Didn't help me. nmap says ```Host is up.``` while Remote Desktop is unavailable yet

Answer (score 2):

Use Task Scheduler to trigger an event when the Windows Remote Management service is started.

Open `Task Scheduler`, click `Create Task`, Select the `Triggers` tab, and click `New`. Choose the `Custom` option under settings and click the `New Event Filter...` button. From there you'll need to drill down in to `Application and Services Logs`, `Microsoft`, `Windows`, and check `Windows Remote management`. Then filter by `Event ID 209` (the service started event) and click Ok.

[image]

As for the action it triggers, I decided to use [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) and create a short batch file:

`C:\blat\blat.exe -to myemail@domain.com -subject "Server is awake" -body "WinRM started on %COMPUTERNAME%!"`

[image]

You could configure all this using a GPO if you want this notification on multiple servers/computers. Keep in mind though it's going to send you this email every time the service is started, not just when the computer is rebooted. That could get annoying.